# How do you build a KDTree in Java

Tags: java, nearest-neighbor, kdtree

I've looked at a couple of implementations and they are kind of confusing, and I would appreciate some sort of breakdown of what I need to build a KDTree from a list of points. Im going to end up using this KDTree to perform a 2D K-nearest-neighbors search.

Here's what I have so far, which isn't much.

Point Class

```
   class Point{
   public PVector p;

   public Point(float x, float y){
     p = new PVector(x,y);
   }

   public Point(PVector _p0 ){
     p = _p0;
   }

   float getX(){ return p.x; }
   float getY(){ return p.y; }

   float x(){ return p.x; }
   float y(){ return p.y; }

   public float distance( Point o ){
     return PVector.dist( p, o.p );
   }
```

Node class

```
class Node{
  Node left;
  Node right;
  Point p;

  Node(Point _p, Node l, Node r){
    p = _p;
    left = l;
    right = r;
  }
}
```

KDTree class

```
class KDTree{
  Node root;

  KDTree()
  {
    root = null;
  }

}
```

As you can see the Node and KDTree class aren't really implemented and that's where I'm stuck.

I want to end up building this KDTree by feeding it something like: ArrayList< Point > points

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to SO. Your question reads as a request for someone to write the KDTree implementation for you. Could I suggest that you read a description of the standard algorithm for balancing the tree at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-d_tree and try implementing it yourself? This forum is best for answering specific technical problems you hit rather than general 'how do I implement X?'

Comment: Yeah I've read the wiki. I'm not really asking for someone to code it out for me, more so i'm asking if my Node class looks accurate, and what kind of functions would I need to implement for the KDTree class.

Comment: Ok I can give some pointers on those things in an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With respect to the structure of your code and the methods you will need to implement, I would suggest it should look something like the following:

```
enum Axis {
    X, Y;

    public Axis next() {
        return values()[(ordinal() + 1) % values().length];
    }
}

interface Node {
    Point closestTo(Point point);
}

class Leaf implements Node {
    private final Point point;

    public Leaf(Point point) {
        this.point = point;
    }

    public Point closestTo(Point point) {
        return this.point;
    }
}

class Branch implements Node {
    private final Axis axis;
    private final Point median;
    private final Node smaller;
    private final Node larger;

    public Branch(Axis axis, Point median, Node smaller, Node larger) {
        this.axis = axis;
        this.median = median;
        this.smaller = smaller;
        this.larger = larger;
    }

    public Point closestTo(Point point) {
        ...
    }
}

class KD_Tree {
    private final Optional<Node> root;

    public KD_Tree(List<Point> points) {
        this.root = makeNode(points);
    }

    private Optional<Node> makeNode(Axis axis, List<Point> points) {
        switch (points.size()) {
            case 0: 
                return Optional.empty();
            case 1: 
                return Optional.of(new Leaf(points.get(0));
            default:
                Point median = medianOf(points);
                Node smaller = makeNode(axis.next(), lessThan(median, points)).get();
                Node larger = makeNode(axis.next(), greaterThan(median, points)).get();
                return Optional.of(new Branch(axis, median, smaller, larger));
        }
    }
}
```

There's plenty of logic still to write there but hopefully that will get you started.